# Java simple Analytics/Event Stream Processing with front end

Tags: java, logging, analytics, esper, graphite

My application takes a lot of measurements of it's internal processes. For example I time certain methods, I time external webservice calls and I also have variables which have a changing value, and processes which have a 'state' (e.g. PAUSED, WAITING etc).

The application uses 100 to 200 threads, and each bit of data would be associated with a particular thread.

I am looking for some software that I can channel all this information into that would produce useful metrics and graphs of the data (ideally in real time or close to real time), let me set thresholds to trigger warnings, would allow me to filter the data by thread or thread group, etc etc.

The application is performing time critical tasks so the software/api would need to be very fast and never block.

The application is written in java, and ideally the software/api would be in java as well. I think what I'm looking for is called Event Stream Processing, but I'm really not sure what language to use to describe it.

All I've found so far are Esper and ERMA. Can anyone give me a recommendation? I'm the only one working on this project so I'm hoping for something that is pretty easy to set up and use, and has a workable front end.

Comment: If you have 100 to 200 threads all processing data at one time, and you are storing it in anything (including memory) there are going to be some blocking i/o during the "save" period in your code.

Comment: Interesting point, I hadn't considered memory IO blocking before. In actual fact only 10-30 threads are actually processing data simultaneously, the rest are sleeping.

Comment: Actually, it's less then that.  If you have a quad core machine (I5), only 4 threads can physically be running at a time.  If you're using a quad core with multi-threading (I7), you can have up to 8 threads running at one time.  Don't forget about OS services either that can (on even a finely tuned system) run about 30 threads.  So if you are trying to run 100 threads in a program on top of that on an I7 (8 threads) your actual processing time is 100/130 * 8 (just over 6 of your threads always processing on average). From there, you still have to add blocking I/O to get true time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found Graphite which was pretty close to being exactly what I wanted. Not the simplest to set up and configure however, but I got it working in the end.

http://graphite.wikidot.com/

In my case I send data directly from my application to Statsd (via UDP), which collects the data and does some pre processing before it ends up in the whisper back end, there is a simple example of a java interface here https://github.com/etsy/statsd/commit/2253223f3c19d2149d65ec5bc802198ff93da4cb

Alternatively you could send your data directly to graphite, example here http://neopatel.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/logging-to-graphite-monitoring-tool.html